# Order statistics: always applicable tool in wireless communication?

Tags: digital-communications, snr, statistics, fading-channel

I have seen few papers where generalized order statistics is used to obtain statistics of the instantaneous SNR.

1. "Performance analysis of monostatic multi-tag backscatter systems with general order tag selection" by Yazan H. Al-Badarneh, Mohamed-Slim Alouini and Costas N. Georghiades.
2. "Order statistics in wireless communications: diversity, adaptation, and scheduling in MIMO and OFDM systems" (Book) by HC Yang, MS Alouini.
3. "A study on the second order statistics of Nakagami-Hoyt mobile fading channels" by N Youssef, CX Wang, M Patzold .

My query is " Is there any particular situation wherein one cannot use generalized order statistics at the receiver ?"

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: ok, third time where you "have seen some papers" but don't tell us which: Citing a paper probably takes you one copy & paste, so please do that. As always, context matters, and we don't know what you've read so far.

Comment: Thank you so much Marcus sir. I forgot to cite the paper, will keep in mind from next time.

Comment: "Performance analysis of monostatic multi-tag backscatter systems with general order tag selection"  This is the paper that I was referring to.

Comment: please **edit** your question to include that citation, including authors, so that we can find it and read it. Also, a single paper is not "a few papers".

Comment: Ok sir....... updated the question....

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first, we'll need to acknowledge that the channels you're looking at are very specifically *about* such a channel. It's no coincidence! In all these papers it's about considering the order statistics as good look at the channel's distribution of SNRs, capacities etc.

Now, in general, you simply do not know the statistics of the channel. So, in most cases you can't use this.

Questions of the type "I found this in literature, can I generally apply it" are usually answered with "no". You will always have to look on what the paper says you can assume to be known. And only scenarios where you know these things can be addressed with a tool. That's not anything special about communications engineering! 
You can only use a hammer when you know where the nails are. If you don't know where the nails are, or whether there's nails at all, you cannot use the hammer :)